# Android, Downloading Data and SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm making an app which has to download some data, parse it and store it in a SQLite Database. However I'm having a problem where the downloadtask (an asynctask) executes everytime the app is launched and keeps appending the duplicate data to the database so I get multiple instances of the same data.

I only want to execute the download task if the database has values in it but still want to be able to run the downloadtask if the data file on the server is updated.

Other than checking if the number of rows in the table is greater than 0 how would I go about doing this? I'm not really sure what to search for. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each reach should have a unique ID. 
When loading the data check if the unique ID is in the database
If it exists update the row.
If it doesnt exist add it(append).
If you control the database in the website, you can put there a flag you update anytime the database is updated. So before reading the data, check your flag. If updated load new and append new data to the database.

Comment: I do have a unique ID for every entry in the table but I only assign that after downloading and parsing the data and this means that I will still have to download and parse data before checking if it is new or not. Isn't that a waste of resources?

Comment: Well unless you put all the load in your web server, there is no other choice. Make sure you do it in an asynctask(). If you have lots of data use a service.

Comment: I can't control the files on the web server because it's hosted on mine and I don't have a web server.

Answer (score 0):

For your local part of the app: Well you can easily update the data as you desires if a query on this database return more than one row. This is very easy using a cursor and getting its count after the query is executed. If you dont want to have duplicates just delete the database after you have made sure that your download task has retrieved the data from the remote source. In that way you won't have duplicates and you will be sure that you don't delete by accident the database if something goes wrong.

For the remote source:You can enable Push Notifications and send one after something is changed in the database.So by sending a notification you can trigger a service that will download the new data and parse it properly.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea?For my app works great and consumes hardly any time!

Comment: It will work no doubt about that and you won't notice the difference when you are dealing with few data.But deleting and recreating a database anytime you want to add or update new data is a bad practice. UPDATE is here for a reason.

Comment: If you dont want to have duplicates then update will not help. For my case at least didnt help at all. I was always getting duplicates when downloading data and trying to update current database!

Comment: Maybe you are doing something wrong. It works fine for me. If you can point me to your source code, I could maybe help.

Comment: i am downloading data in json format then parsing it based on a custom model, and then adding it to contentvalues. Then i insert the contentvalues object to the database!

Comment: Your data has a unique value? A value that is not duplicated? if yes here is a way to do it: database.update(DB_TABLE, cv, KEY_UNIQUEID + "='" + unique_id + "'", null); . INSERT will append.

Comment: Yes it should have a unique row_id that is autoincremented. Every row in the database is unique.

Comment: I was talking about another row, not the row_id. But if you can link your data in the server with the row_id in the database, you can still use update.